# Difference between Model.ids and Model.select(:id).map(&:id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have been trying to find the how rails handles call to **`Model.ids and Model.select(:id).map(&:id)`**

When i try to execute the same in console i see the difference

Model.ids doesn't load the Active Record Model

However, Model.select(:id).map(&:id), loads the active record model.

**Can anyone please share as to when Rails will load the active record model and when not.**

Also, does loading active record model have any advantages / dis advantages or vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Model.ids` is equivalent to

```
Model.pluck(:id)
```

And is the faster method as the database returns the array for you.

```
Model.select(:id)
```

...returns the table rows (Model objects) but with only the `:id` attribute, so you then use the `#map` method to get the `:id` array.

```
Model.select(:id).map(&:id)
```

So because this creates an active record relation of objects that then need to be processed by `#map` this is less efficient.

So `Model.ids` is preferred.

In general, the `.pluck` used directly or indirectly does not load the active_record models.  `.select` does.  `.where` and `.order` by design automatically include the db `SELECT` call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer steve, can you please let me know, what are some additional methods in which we directly get response from database? And how do we identify such methods. can you point me to some docs?

Comment: This is a good guide, and shows the SQL equivalent for each ActiveRecord command.   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html